# How can I remove the number of the heading?

Tags: r-markdown

Every time I try to do a heading with #, it appears a number before the title. How could I still use the #, ##, ### method, but without the appearance of a number? Just with the change of the font size.

For example:

```
# **Activity 1**

## **1a**
```

This appears like:

**1 Activity 1**

**1.1. 1a**

I only want to get a bigger title for "Activity 1" and a smaller title for "1a". How could I remove the number?

Thank you,

Alicia

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To suppress numbering for a specific heading, place `{-}` after it:

```
# **Activity 1** {-}

## **1a** {-}
```

To suppress all heading numbering, try `knitr::opts_chunk$set(number_sections = FALSE)`.